# How does associativity of operator work during evaluation of expression?

Tags: c++, right-to-left, conditional-operator, associativity, left-to-right

I was learning precedence rule in C++. In which conditional operator is said to have Right to Left associativity. 
I interpret this as evaluation of expression start from right and proceed to left. 
So, for the below code-

```
int a=1, b=2, c;
c=a>b? a=a*2: a=a+3;
cout<<c<<" "<<a;
```

I assume output as

```
8 8
```

But actual output is

```
4 4
```

I don't understand how actually this associativity works, because from the above output it seems to me conditional operator have left to right associativity.

Comment: Why would you expect `8`? Only one of the two branches execute, not both.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence , https://en.cppreference.com/book/operator_precedence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Associativity tells you what happens if you have multiple instances of the same operator in a row. For example,

```
f() - g() - h()
```

parses as

```
(f() - g()) - h()
```

and not

```
f() - (g() - h())
```

because `-` is left associative, not right associative.

None of this has anything to do with evaluation order, which determines which function is called first.

As for `?:` being right associative, it means

```
a ? b : c ? d : e
```

parses as

```
a ? b : (c ? d : e)
```

(This makes slightly more sense if you think of `?...:` as a single operator.)

However, `?:` guarantees left-to-right evaluation: The first operand is always evaluated first, then exactly one of the other operands (depending on the truth value of the first result).

---

In your example,

```
c=a>b? a=a*2: a=a+3
```

(please never put assignments inside `?:` like that in real code) is parsed as

```
c = ((a>b) ? (a=a*2) : (a=a+3))
```

This is entirely due to precedence, not associativity (we don't have multiple identical operators next to each other here).

`a>b` is evaluated first (yielding `false`), which causes `a=a+3` to be evaluated (yielding `4`), which is then assigned to `c`.

Comment: That means associativity rule apply only if ( there is another opaertor of same precedence present in expression, ) otherwise not.